# How to parse a multi-select parameter in rails for Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I am using Rails 4 with Sunspot and my setup is:

```
searchable do
     text :title
     text :body
     integer :technicalarea_ids, :references => Technicalarea, :multiple => true
     integer :targetgroup_ids, :references => Targetgroup, :multiple => true
     integer :organization_id, :references => Organization
     integer :series_id, :references => Series`    searchable do
end
```

My form select to technical area:

```
 <%= collection_select :technicalarea_ids, :id, Technicalarea.all, :id, :name,{}, { :multiple => true, :include_blank => false} %>
```

and my search controller

```
  @search = Resource.search do
      fulltext params[:search_term]
      with(:technicalarea_ids, params[:technicalarea_ids])
  end
```

on form submit the params[:technicalarea_ids] show this

```
-- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
id:
- ''
- '2'
- '3'
- '4'
```

two issues...
one is the with() search code won't work right if there is a blank. I can take care of that with a `.reject { |c| c.empty? }` function .... **but only if its a clean array without the id: involved** at the beginning

right i am getting this error:

```
undefined method `to_i' for {"id"=>["", "2", "3", ,4"]}:ActionController::Parameters
```

How can i sent the parameter from the form looking like:
technicalarea_ids =>  ["", "2", "3", ,4"]
without the preceding "id"=>   ?

Comment: Ok, i solved my own problem....

Answer (score 0):

i changed the form select to the following and it works just fine....

```
<%= select_tag "technicalarea_ids", options_from_collection_for_select(Technicalarea.all, "id", "name"), { :multiple => true, :include_blank => true} %>
```

i think the `select_tag` was the big change instead of `collection_select`

onwards...